# How to connect entities in core data

Tags: database, cocoa, core-data

I have three entities - Documents, Contragents and Products.

Document has:
id - int64
contragentId - int64
paymentMethod - String
documentDate - Date
documentKind - String

Contragents has
id - int64
name - String
address - String

Products has
id - int64
sku - String
productQuantity - int64
description - String
unitValue - Decimal
totalValue - Decimal
isTemp - Bool

i have implemented Products subclassing the model and totalValue = quantity * unitValue

i want in another table to keep all Documents, but i don't know how to display Contragent.name 
i should use that **Document.contragentId = Contragent.id**

```
    - (IBAction) createDocument:(id)sender
{
    //create new document
NSManagedObject *document = [NSEntityDescription
                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Documents"
                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [_documentNumber integerValue]];
[document setValue: num  forKey:@"id"];
[document setValue: [_documentKind stringValue]  forKey:@"documentKind"];
[document setValue: [_documentDate dateValue]  forKey:@"documentDate"];
[document setValue: [_paymentMethod stringValue]  forKey:@"paymentMethod"];
[_documentNumber setIntegerValue:[_documentNumber integerValue]+1];

//get ID
//NSString *contragentId = [[_contragents selectedObjects] valueForKey:@"eik"];
//NSLog(@"The customer ID is: %@", contragentId);

document.contragent = [_contragents selectedObjects];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Core Data one does not use "foreign keys" to identify rows of another table, but *relationships* between entities.

So instead of `contragentId`, you should define a relationship "contragent"
from the "Document" entity to the "Contragent" entity. (I have used the singular form "Contragent" because that seems to be more natural. But I have no idea what a contragent 
is.)

You should also define the "inverse relationship" from "Contragent" to "Document".
If a "Contragent" object can be connected to several "Document" objects, the inverse
relationship is "to-many", otherwise "to-one".

Then you make connections just be setting the relationship:

```
Document *theDocument = ...
Contragent *theContragent = ...
theDocument.contragent = theContragent; // --> connected!
```

And getting the contragent name for a document:

```
Document *theDocument = ...
NSString *contrName = theDocument.contragent.name;
```

Comment: I can't understand the connection with code you show.I need to connect selected object's is to the Document's contragentId NSString *contragentId = [[_contragents selectedObjects] valueForKey:@"objectID"];

Comment: @user2414590: You should not use a `contragentId` attribute, as I wrote in my answer. Use a relationship instead. - Perhaps you can add the relevant code to your question so that I can help better.

Comment: Thanks for your time.I already done the relationship Documents->Contragents and vice versa.Now in the IBAction when i add new record of Document i need to specify the connection in order the new record's documentContragent to point to the id of the Contragent.

Comment: I want to know how to make core data knows which Contragent is selected in order to bind it to the particular Document.The code you show Document * is a bit strange to me, on this way i can't create a object.Meaning using the Entity name

Comment: @user2414590: "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass ..." in the Xcode menu creates classes `Document` and `Contragent`. Then include "Document.h" and "Contragent.h" in your source file. Now you can use the entity names as classes: `Document *doc`, and the accessor methods as in my answer.

Comment: Thank you.I understand this, but as i understand , the idea is not to set the ID of the Contragent, but tell on some way to which Contragent to point.How?I want to pint to the selected item of Contragents.

Comment: @user2414590: That's what I tried to explain in the answer. If `theDocument` is some Document object, and `theContragent` is some Contragent object, then you make the connection with `theDocument.contragent = theContragent` (or alternatively: `[theDocument setValue:theContragent forKey:@"contragent"]`).

Comment: It's what i do:Documents *newDoc;
    Contragents *newContr;
    newDoc.contragent = newContr;
    
    [document setValue: newContr.name  forKey:@"contragent"]; But it didn't get the selected Contragent!

Comment: The first statement `newDoc.contragent = newContr;` is correct and makes the connection. The next statement looks wrong. What do you mean by "the selected Contragent"? To get the Contragent name of a document, use `NSString *name = theDoc.contragent.name`.

Comment: Dear Martin, i have a table, and the selected item should be set as contragent for the current document

Comment: see what exactly i want to do( the code above) , but it shows me that document has no property contragent

Comment: @user2414590: Then you have not created the relationship "contragent" correctly, or you have not re-created the Document.h, Document.m files.

Comment: Yes, as you see i user document, but how i have to create the relationship in order to use the selection.

Comment: Why should i recreate these documents?As you can see i created *document as new record of Documents.

Comment: Dear Martin, in my head now is a big mess.I have a table from which i pick one Contragent(i select him) , than i have some textfields with some inputs and below a button.When click on the button i want to creadte a object(instance of Documents) and one of the properties of this Document should point to the selected contragent.About the relationship in Documents i created new relation which points to Contragents.I also created relationship in Contragents which points to Documents.

Comment: @user2414590: I did not say that you should recreate the document. I said that you *might* have to recreate the *source files* Document.h, Document.m with Xcode -> Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass ...". – `newDoc.contragent = selectedContr;` should just work to make the connection. – I am sorry, I don't know how to help more ...

Comment: Dear Martin , you mean that i have to write this in the implementation of the Documents, Contragents file, not in the AppController?

Comment: [document setValue:[_contragents selectedObjects]  forKey:@"contragent"];-[__NSArrayI managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100125470

Comment: @user2414590: I am sorry, but I really don't know how to solve your problems.

Comment: Martin, i understood that the problem is in the [_contragents selectedObjects].It seems that doesn't return an object.I tried to create new ManagedObject from the Contragent entity and than set it as value and everything worked.Now i need to know how to get selectedObject and set it as value

Comment: Finally [document setValue:[[_contragents selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"contragent"];